# Mongo error detected during query over particluar collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongo server over a collection with huge data an error is thrown and multiple concurrent connections are opened and not getting closed.

Error :

Mongo error detected during fetching data query over a particular collection { $err: "unauthorized db: collection lock type:0 ", code: 10057 }

ClientCursor::find(): cursor not found in map -1 (ok after a drop)

Any thoughts what could be causing the problem.

Mongo version:2.2.0

Comment: Not enough information here for anyone to provide any further advice, and the only advice that is on topic here is the code related to what is happening. Save that, MongoDB 2.2 is a very old release.  You should consider upgrading, and on a path to at least 2.6 as the current previous version. Discussion further related to locking levels and schema distribution should be held on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead, where it is more suited.